# Trying to create an array to target objects for animation

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have maps of districts named mc_1, mc_2, mc_3 etc...
I'm triggering an event when mouse hovers over them. Instead of writing code for each mc_n I thought I could use arrays. But I havent done that before.
Currently I have

```
var district = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
district[i] = "mc_" + i;
}

stage.enableMouseOver(3);

this.district[i].on('mouseover', function(){

    this.district[i].gotoAndPlay(2);

});
```

Comment: What would be the expected output? Thanks!

Comment: What are `mc_1` here? Dom element id?

Comment: This is an Adobe Animate project. mc_1, mc_2...is a Movieclip that holds a bitmap.
Expected output is an animation that that gets triggered at the second frame of the movieclip.

Answer (score 0):

After the `for` loop, there is no more `i` variable, instead you can use `forEach`:

```js
var district = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
     district[i] = document.getElementById("mc_" + i); // get the DOM elements by ID
}

stage.enableMouseOver(3);

this.district.forEach( (el) => { // loop through the DOM elements 
    el.on('mouseover', function(){ // add the muoseover event to the current element
       el.gotoAndPlay(2);
    });
});
```

But if you want to apply the same behavior to all of those elements, i would suggest to use CSS classes in order to identify them.